# Crystal reports showing numbers as hash #

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, ado.net

I have an Access database which has some number fields.

Crystal reports is taking everything else properly but numbers as hash, and I don't know why but when I export it to PDF, everything is back to normal.

Those fields are in numbers in database using VS2010 ACCDB2010 SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS....

Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you widen the column?

Comment: number of hash increases

Comment: What is the type and size of the field?  If you browse the data, what do you see?  If you make the column really wide (say 3"), do you still see #####?

Comment: its a number field and i;ve jus tried to make the field very long it seems this way 567,567,565 where the data is 56767565?

Comment: and wherever i have numbers it adds a comma treid false to thousand separater didnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to the design tool, you can easily change the column's format.

With the field selected, click this once:

[image]

Then, click this twice:

[image]

It should then look like this:

[image]